# Is it safe to upgrade to 22.04 with Software Updater?

Tags: upgrade

[image]

I'm visually impaired and apologize if this is a FAQ. I'm using 20.04 now and the Software Upgrader is offering to upgrade to 22.04 for me. I've always upgraded to new LTS the old-fashioned way with a bootable CD or thumb drive. My vision is not good and I wonder if it's safe to upgrade this way...small text is hard for me to read, but videos are helpful. Thanks Jim (Ubuntu since 2009)

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot, not sure it worked  duhh

Comment: It is never 100% safe. But I did it a couple of times recently. Had to fix some things ;-) Make a backup and try.

Comment: Thank you, hope I dont have to reinstall Dropbox and One Drive. What a pain

Answer (score 1):

It is rather safe, but never absolutely safe. There is some chance of some issues, there is a smaller chance of larger problems.

If you have a good backup of your date, you have nothing to loose though. So first make sure your backup is up to date. Then go ahead with the system update.

Comment: Ohh thank you so much! How about my Chromium browser? What about Thunderbird settings? Plus my software like One Drive and Dropbox?

Comment: You can save the Chromium and Thunderbird settings by copying the right directories from your profile. Show hidden files and folders and all should become clear pretty quickly. I backup my entire ~/ and call it good these days.